# ui-sref-active in dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using below code

```
<li class="dropdown" ui-sref-active="activeclassroot">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ui-sref-active="activeclasschild"><a ui-sref="products1" >products1</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="activeclasschild"><a ui-sref="products2" >products2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here **activeclasschild** class is getting applied successfully. Is there any way to apply **activeclassroot** class to the root **li** if any of the child links are active?